# crosstab - plot - how to return a bar chart with the top 5

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart, crosstab

I want to return only the top 5 teams that gained the maximum medals (gold, silver and Bronze) in the plot.

```
medal_ranks = olympics[olympics['Medal'] != 'NaN'].groupby(['NOC', 'Year', 'Sport', 'Event', 'Season'])
medal_ranks = medal_ranks.first()
medal_ranks = medal_ranks.reset_index()
medal_ranks['NOC'].value_counts().head(5)

medal_colors = ['darkgoldenrod', 'gold', 'silver']
cross = pd.crosstab(medal_ranks.NOC, medal_ranks.Medal).plot(kind='bar',color = medal_colors, 
                                                  stacked=True, figsize=(18,5))
```

[image: This is the output now:]

(The Teams that I want to show:
USA    5261
GBR    4152
FRA    4135
ITA    3738
CAN    3649)

Comment: well, you didn't make any selection of data. Furthermore, if I understand correctly NOC is the country??, in that case value_counts only returns the number of examples of each country.

Comment: I think you should groupy country only

Comment: NOC is the team, I want the bar chart to return the 5 teams that gained the most 'examples' as you say with the bar chart. to order it by it.

Comment: and return the maximum 5

Comment: Ah Ok,  I understand better now I believe.

Comment: OK, I think the answer from @jezrael is correct than.

Comment: I can't see any answer... Which oneare you talking about?

Comment: top = medal_ranks['NOC'].value_counts().head(5).index

Comment: medal_ranks = medal_ranks[medal_ranks['NOC'].isin(top)]